# Strange requests behavior when setting cookie value to None in the method-level parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

In the *requests* documentation, section [Session objects](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), there's a following remark:

> ### Remove a Value From a Dict Parameter
>
> Sometimes you’ll want to omit session-level keys from a dict parameter. To do this, you simply set that key’s value to None in the method-level parameter. It will automatically be omitted.

I tested it with slightly modified examples from the documentation section.

After running

```
s = requests.Session()
s.cookies.update({'from-my': 'browser'})
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies={'from-my': None})
print r.text
```

I get

```
{
  "cookies": {}
}
```

which is consistent with the remark.

However, the output of

```
s = requests.Session()
s.cookies.update({'from-my': 'browser'})
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies={'another': 'cookie', 'from-my': None})
print r.text
```

is

```
{
  "cookies": {
    "from-my; another": "cookie"
  }
}
```

so it looks like there is a cookie named `from-my; another`. Whereas, according to the remark, the output should rather be

```
{
  "cookies": {
    "another": "cookie"
  }
}
```

I use Python 2.7.6 and *requests* 2.7.0.

Can it be a problem with *requests* or *httplib.org* — or am I just misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: Looks like a bug, it works for me intermittently using python3 but not at all  using python2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: which indicates that dictionary ordering plays a role there (hash randomisation causes a different order).

Comment: Sounds like you have an excellent bug report here to post to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep, that  makes sense.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @PadraicCunningham, thank you also for testing the code in Python 3. I've created a bug report; it is available at the following link: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2716. I guess one of us can post an answer to this question when the bug will be confirmed.